# Loading apache logs in amazon redshift

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to load apache-style logs into an amazon redshift cluster using their COPY command (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html), but there are some problems with the date parsing. My dates look like this:

`[10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700]`

The redshift [time format docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEFORMAT_and_TIMEFORMAT_strings.html
say that "You must specify a space character between the date and time sections". Since I have a colon between them in actual fact, I checked what happens if I use that in my time format, and the result is nominal success, but minute and second are set to zero.

(The timezone is another problem, but it sounds like there is no intent to support that currently, so I deal with it separately)

So, my questions:

1. Is there any way to parse this using COPY?
2. Else, I believe I have to pre-process the log files on EC2, or load the dates as strings and parse them into a proper timestamp column on redshift. Any advice about which is preferable?

Comment: I'm having the identical problem.  The only workaround I found to date is the solution you have already discovered.

Answer (score 3):

Now Amazon Redshift supports parsing the timestamp format of Apache access logs with TIMEFORMAT 'auto' option for COPY command.
Here is an example.

```
CREATE TABLE time_test (time_text VARCHAR, time TIMESTAMP);
COPY time_test from 's3://[bucket-name]/[file-path or prefix]' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxx' DELIMITER '\t' TIMEFORMAT 'auto';
SELECT * FROM time_test;

          time_text           |        time
------------------------------+---------------------
 [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] | 2000-10-10 13:55:36
```

Here is the sample TSV data.

```
[10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700]     [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700]
```

Also this option works with INSERT and UPDATE. You can get the same result with the following sql.

```
INSERT INTO time_test VALUES ('[10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700]', '[10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700]');
```

However, in this example, the timezone part(-0700) is ignored because Amazon Redshift still does not support the timezone. If you use this way, you should handle the timezone issue separately like writing log data with UTC timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the timezone formats and load them as such. 
For example I am doing this:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)T(\d\d\:\d\d:\d{2}\.\d{3})Z/\1 \2/g' $FILENAME
```

Where in the file has date and time in format `2013-07-31T03:59:41.000Z` 
.The perl command above converts this into `2013-07-31 03:59:41.000` which loads absolutely fine into a datetime field. Assuming that the time loaded is UTC, you could use `convert_timezone`.